# Laravel Collective SelectBox Edit population

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I want to populate the whole Edit form, but SelectBox dose not grab the value and always stays on the first one.

**My Forms Select:**

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('buyer') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
{{ Form::label('buyer', __('Klientas')) }}
{{ Form::select('buyer[]', $clients, null, ['class' => 'form-control select2']) }}
{!! $errors->first('buyer','<p class="text-danger"><strong>:message</strong></p>') !!}
</div>
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function edit($id){
   return view('boilerplate::purchases.edit', [ 'purchases' => Purchase::find($id), 'clients' => Clients::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray()]);
    }
```

In the photo there is the RED option selected, but it should be blue.
[Check the photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iduur.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using model bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviewing the [Laravel Collective HTML package documentation for Form Model Binding](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#form-model-binding) it states the following about value precedence:

> Now, when you generate a form element, like a text input, the model's value matching the field's name will automatically be set as the field value. So, for example, for a text input named email, the user model's email attribute would be set as the value. However, there's more! If there is an item in the Session flash data matching the input name, that will take precedence over the model's value. So, the priority looks like this:
>
> - Session Flash Data (Old Input)
> - Explicitly Passed Value
> - Model Attribute Data

As we can see from your `select` declaration, you are explicitly setting the `selected` value to `null` and as per the order of precedence above, that `null` value is a higher priority than the bound model value.

```
{{ Form::select('buyer[]', $clients, null, ['class' => 'form-control select2']) }}
```

To resolve this issue you will need to explicitly provide the selected value:

```
{{ Form::select('buyer[]', $clients, $model->client, ['class' => 'form-control select2']) }}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I figured that I wasn't telling the field what kind of value it is. P.S: With Laravel Collective if you set text and etc values to 'null' only then it fills the whole form.